# c language type conversion

Tags: pointers, casting, char, int, type-conversion

I'm not able to understand the output of this simple c code.What happens when we typecast a int value to char pointer?

```
int main(void) {
int a =320;
char *ptr;
ptr=(char *)&a;
printf("%d",*ptr);  
return 0;
}
```

the output is 64.But I'm unable to figure out the logic.Does the size of the signed char play a role here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

320 is `0x140` in hex. A char is one byte (Two hexadecimal digits), so casting and printing with `%d` will print the decimal value of `0x40`, which happens to be 64.

Comment: Thanks...can you please tell why 320 is first converted to hex? Is it due to computer architecture or c language architecture?Thanks in advance

Comment: It isn't converted to hex; I converted it for the example :-). `0x140` **is** 320 in hex. When working with bits and bytes, it's far easier to work with hex than decimal. If 8 bits is one byte, how do you explain that in decimal format?

Comment: k...now I can understand...the largest value unsigned char can take is 255...and signed char is 127(-128 being lower end) so the leading nibble of 320 is neglected...thank you